# Telegram pyTelegramBotAPI MarkDown применяется только первые 100 разметок

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, markdown

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['test', 'тест'])
def test_func(message):
    message_text=''
    for i in range(150):
        message_text+='`' + 'текст' + str(i+1)+'`' +'\n'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message_text, parse_mode='Markdown')

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Здравствуйте, мне нужно выводить ботом в сообщении много строк, и каждая должна иметь возможность скопироваться при клике - для этого заключаю каждую строку в '`' и добавляю parse_mode='Markdown' (с MarkdownV2 - то же самое). Разметка применяется только первые 100 раз. Через parse_mode='HTML' и тег code аналогично только первые 100. Это какое-то ограничение телеграма (не нашел такой информации в документации)? Код просто для примера, и соответственно результат:
[image: результат]

Как-то можно расширить применение на большее количество, или только дроблением сообщений по 100 строк?

Comment: А если жирный текст делать, тоже первые 100 выделит? Если да, то похоже на багу. Или незадокументированное ограничение

Comment: да, проверил, с выделением жирным (через *) тоже только первые 100.